# Looking for references - ReLU neural networks vs Fitting continuous piecewise linear function

Tags: neural-networks, fitting, curve-fitting, splines, piecewise-linear

ReLU activated neural networks with a linear output are continuous piecewise 
linear functions (CPLF). There are technuques to fit CPLF functions, so comparison of those methods seems very natural, yet I was not able to find academic work which carries this out.

I'm doing research in machine learning and am studying neural networks from a more theoretical point of view. In this context I trying to find results that compare performance of fitting a CPLF and fitting ReLU activated nets on a similar high dimensional data set, for example fitting [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

So I'm wondering if CPLF fitting is so unefficient compared to neural networks,  that it cannot be applied to high dimensional data or large data set? Or I just missed the litrature on the subject.

Any comments are welcome!

---

Here is a [paper](http://www.mit.edu/~jvielma/publications/Fitting-Piecewise-Linear.pdf) by Alejandro Toriello (2011) that provides an overview of fitting CPLF.